# Hourly Cron job will not run but will manually run fine

Tags: linux, ruby, crontab

Background - the system has two different versions of ruby installed.  I need to use the latest version to run this monitor script i've created

This is my crontab line:

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby /home/nexpose/ruby/console_monitor.rb
```

When I run this:

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby /home/nexpose/ruby/console_monitor.rb

it works as expected and even sends me an email as designed

When I check syslog I don't see much.  I see that its being executed but no errors shown..

```
 # which ruby
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
 # ruby -v
 ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]
```

Does this have to do with my PATH configuration?  I thought I was bypassing this by pointing directly to the ruby binary?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that cron jobs have minimal environment settings. They do not have the settings you see in an interactive shell.  Cron does not execute `~/.login`, `~/.bashrc`, etc.

To see errors from a cron job, I find it most convenient to redirect STDOUT and STDERR to a file. e.g append `> /tmp/cron.out 2>&1` to the crontab entry. Otherwise your system might package the output into an email message to the owner of the crontab.